# Can a Facebook Application send a message to its users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph

Is it possible for a Facebook application  to send a message to its users ? Sending the Message that we get next to notification(inbox) .On behalf of the Application. ?

Comment: What do you mean by message? a private message? Also, sending it on the behalf of the application or a user using the application?

Comment: Sending the Message that we get next to notification(inbox) .On behalf of the Application. ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The facebook api does not allow sending private messages (inbox) at all, not for an application or a user by an application.

For user (with a user access token) applications can use the [Send Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) or the [Chat API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/).

As for sending user notifications from the application, check the [Social Channels](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/) and [Requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/) documentation.